# What are important characteristics of a reliable and safe parabolic flight company?

Tags: air-travel, adventure

For some years now I've been interested in parabolic flights to get the feeling of zero gravity. There are various companies that offer such flights, especially in Russia.

I'm not sure how to choose a company, since I don't really know what important facts I have to look for.

So: What are important characteristics of a reliable and safe parabolic flight company?

Comment: Aren't they called *parabolic* flights?

Comment: I'm not sure, in German it is called Parabelflug. So I just translated it ;)

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks, I checked it and you were right. Corrected the question.

Comment: Wikipedia calls them [Vomit Comet flights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vomit_Comet), and says they follow an elliptical flight path that's almost parabolic. A *parable* is normally a story which illustrates a universal truth, which is rather different!

Comment: Yes, I did a common error when translating something in a foreign language. How is a curve like e.g. y=x^2 called in English? Isn't that a parable as in German?

Comment: That's a [parabola](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola).

Comment: That's a [parabola](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola), but we're verging into the territory of other SE sites here... :)

Comment: Yes that's true, but it is called a Parabel in German, because the form of the flight remembers a parabola. But now back to topic ;)

Comment: Well forms of flights cant remember anything because they don't have memories. But that's even more off topic! (-;

Comment: Ah I should have written resemble .... I'm going to bed now... too late.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For safety, consider the aircraft age and the company operating the flights. A larger, well established company is less likely to skimp on maintenance and crew. A newer plane costs more, and is probably safer. Germany has tighter aviation safety standards than Russia.

Comment: Can you give me a link to a german company that offers that? I never found one.

Comment: IL-76 is safe air-craft, and there is no need to worry about safety in this case. Also, all the companies providing such tour are located in France.

Comment: @VMAtm: What do you mean by "safe aircraft" exactly? I'm not claiming the IL-76 would be particularly unsafe, but it has been involved in several [incidents and accidents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilyushin_Il-76#Incidents_and_accidents) even in recent years.

Comment: Zero-G has flown an A300 in Germany in the past. I'm not sure whether they still do:  http://www.dlr.de/en/desktopdefault.aspx/tabid-734/1210_read-3259/

Comment: @Jonik I've reading [this article](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BB-76#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.87.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F), and, according to it, most of the accidents were because of war or human factor. Also I want to note that IL-76 MDK is stronly powerized for the near-cosmos flights. Thats all I wanted to say.

Answer (score 6):

See the [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vomit_Comet#Usage_by_NASA) for general reference about [countries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vomit_Comet#Outside_of_NASA) who used such flights.
About booking the tickets from USA for such flights see [this article](http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/5992077/)
[Russian company](http://en.starcity-tours.ru/category/zvezdny/zerogravity/) for such flights

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea how good or reliable this company is, I only remember seeing them [in a Cracked.com article](http://www.cracked.com/article_19368_6-shockingly-affordable-sci-fi-inventions.html). The company is called [Zero G Corporation](http://www.gozerog.com/) and they offer zero gravity flights in the US on modified Boeing 727 aircrafts. FAA certification in the US is fairly rigorous (or at least I would like to believe so!) and thus this seems to be a 'safe' option.